# Find longest word C with recursion

Tags: c, string, recursion

I'm trying to find the size of the longest word in an array of structs.
I have this array of structs:

```
struct Vocabolo{
    char parola[20];
    char *sinonimi[5];
    char definizione[300];
    };
typedef Vocabolo vocabolo;
vocabolo parole[30];
```

Now I have to use incremental recursion in order to find the size of the lognest word in the array. Words are contained each in:

```
parole[n].parola
```

I'm using this code:

```
int Lunghezza_parola(vocabolo *parole,int n){
    int y;
    if(n == 1)
        return strlen(parole[0].parola);
    else {
        y = strlen(parole[n-1].parola);
        return Scegli_max(y,Lunghezza_parola(&parole,n-1));

    }
}
```

Wnere `Scegli_max` is:

```
int Scegli_max(int y, int lunghezzaStringa){
    if (y >= lunghezzaStringa)
        return y;
    else
        return lunghezzaStringa;
}
```

In this program the user has to insert words manually and each time a word is inserted, the program should put them in alphabetical order.

If I try to input something like "come" as `parole[0].parola` and "hi" `parole[1].parola` and start this function the result is 3. Also it seems to works only if the longest word is in the last position of the array.

Any idea?

PS: this is part of a longer programm so is impossible to write here all the code but i'm quite sure everithing works fine exept this function so the words are ordered correctly in the array of struct.

Comment: please, use English identifier in your code example

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `return Scegli_max(y,Lunghezza_parola(&parole,n-1));`

You call Lunghezza_parola giving it &parole which is already a `vocabolo *parole` so this becomes a `vocabolo **parole` and the pointer is now invalid.

Try changing your return to `return Scegli_max(y,Lunghezza_parola(parole,n-1));`

Comment: How a tiny typo can make your life a nightmare for days... Glad you made it.

(Do not forget to accept the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the line `return Scegli_max(y,Lunghezza_parola(&parole,n-1));` . remove the `&`.

You should pass the value of the pointer, not a pointer to it.